# Ant setter execution depends on attribute location

Tags: java, ant

This has got me stumped.

I've written an ant task which sets a logging level via an attribute (logLevel="INFO"). The setter is implemented like this

```
public void setLogLevel(String logLevel) {
    System.out.println("Log level passed to ant task: " + logLevel);
    this.level = Level.toLevel(logLevel);
    System.out.println("Log level set to " + level.toString());
}
```

When I tested the task this setter never executed, even though the attribute was correctly spelled and set. After a lot of hair pulling I decided to try something that shouldn't matter; I moved the logLevel attribute ahead of my other attributes (it was next to last). Guess what - that change caused to setter to execute.

I changed the attribute back and forth several times to make sure this made a difference, it does. If the attribute is one of the first ones encountered, the setter executes and the attribute is set. If it's one of the last encountered, the setter does not execute.

I've seen this behavior in both Ant 1.7.1 and 1.9.0. Can anyone tell me why this strange behavior is happening and what I might be doing wrong? My task has 15 attributes and the logLevel attribute is not set when it is the 11th attribute or lower.

Per Martin Clayton here is the xml fragment from the build.xml file. The logLevel attribute is set here but if I move it down a few lines it will not be set.

```
        <testReport report="${report}/report.xml" 
        logLevel="${logLevel}"
        highestSeverityCountProperty="highestCount"
        highSeverityCountProperty="highCount" 
        mediumSeverityCountProperty="mediumCount"
        lowSeverityCountProperty="lowCount" 
        lowestSeverityCountProperty="lowestCount"
        totalViolationsCountProperty="totalCount"
        failOnHighestSeverityCount="${lvl1ViolationsFailValue}" 
        failOnHighSeverityCount="${lvl2ViolationsFailValue}"
        failOnMeidumSeverityCount="${lvl3ViolationsFailValue}" 
        failOnLowSeverityCount="${lvl4ViolationsFailValue}"
        failOnLowestSeverityCount="${lvl5ViolationsFailValue}" 
        failOnTotalViolationsCount="${totalViolationsFailValue}"
        failureReason="failMessage"/>
```

Comment: If the problem is not inside the setter, but whether it gets called or not, please consider changing the information provided in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I'm having is that not all attributes get set. This problem does not happen in an ant build from a command line or eclipse. It happens during ant builds using the IBM Rational Team Concert Jazz Build Engine.

I don't know what the problem is but I have found a workaround using dynamic ant tasks without setters. See [here](http://myarch.com/ant-task-without-setters/) for a simple description. This worked for me.